# Type of a total function where the first parameter is a partial function

Tags: terminology

Consider any *partial function* $f \colon \subseteq X \to Y$ for arbitrary sets $X,Y$. Now assume that a *total function* $g$ takes any such function $f$ as a first paramter and as a second parameter a natural number from $\mathbb N$ and returns an integer from $\mathbb{Z}$. I'm now wondering how the type of $g$ looks like. First I thought about something like that:

$$g\colon \subseteq (X \to Y) \to \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{Z}$$

I'm wondering if this is the correct notation, i.e., is the subset inclusion $\subseteq$ at the right position? Or is that type to general, i.e., would it mean that $g$ is a partial function---what I assume is the case. Then consider the following type:

$$g\colon (\subseteq X \to Y) \to \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{Z}$$

Is this the correct notation, i.e., does it mean that $g$ is a total function, i.e., defined for all partial functions $\subseteq X \to Y$ as a first parameter and for all natural numbers as the second parameter?

Comment: The second one is OK; you might argue that it should be $g : ((\subseteq X) \to Y) \to \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{Z}$, just to be clear of the scoping of the "partial" symbol.